# Oracle JDBC Datasource set auto commit property to false to all connections

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, datasource

I have this bean:

```
public DataSource getDatsource() throws SQLException {
    OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser(userName);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setURL(wallet);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("AutoCommit", false); // not working
    dataSource.setConnectionProperties(props );
    return dataSource;
}
```

I would set up datasource like all the connection generated from it, has auto commit to false.

How can I do it?

PS I know `-Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false` and works, but I would set the property hard coded.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `dataSource.SetAutoCommit(false)`?

Comment: OracleDatasource if don't have setautocommit. Connection has it

Comment: Why do you think that the Oracle datasource has a property called AutoCommit? In any case, if `-Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false` works, have you tried using `props.put("oracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant",  "false")`?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
public DataSource getDefaultDataSource() throws SQLException {
    OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser(userName);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setURL(wallet);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("oracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant", "false");
    dataSource.setConnectionProperties(props );
    return dataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value should be a String not a Boolean:

```
props.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_AUTOCOMMIT, "false");
```